# Samsaric knowledge

Tags: samsara, reincarnation

I learn new things every day, which on use becomes knowledge and wisdom over the years. From Buddhism point of view, I can reincarnate in different world and time , can remember my previous birth. What does Buddhism say of samsaric knowledge gained on previous birth? Is it accessible to new reincarnate being?

Answer (score 4):

Habits practiced over many lifetimes persist. Say there is monkey born as a monkey over 500 lifetimes and subsequently born human. The tendency to be a bit jumpy will persist.

The other knowledge you cannot access unless you develop the ability to recall past life. This is not easy and developing these kind of abilities are not connected to the Buddhist goal hence not encouraged.

Without such ability and an average person so cannot access past life knowledge you will most likely not be able to do in this and future lives also.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Tibetan tradition, some children can remember fragments of their previous life, based on the tradition preserved in the Pali Canon that one can intentionally influence one's future rebirths. These children are tulkus, intentional rebirths of somewhat advanced beings (not necessarily "masters" as commonly asserted). Moreover, the Buddha remembered all of his previous lives, which is paradoxical since samsara is beginningless, as noted by Dr. Richard Gombrich. Therefore, the karmic continuum, mindstream or santana, must include memory. However, this is not normally accessible and is usually "overwritten" early in life due to the greater immediacy and intensity of current experience. Dr. Ian Stevenson has documented this is to some extent.

Comment: "based on the tradition preserved in the Pali Canon that one can intentionally influence one's future rebirth" Atma is not sure that such is so but rather remembers the Sutta where the Buddha illustrated rebirth like a thrown stick, sometimes falling on the top, side or the other side, Mr. Duncan. All your current knowledge requires a lot of gratitude, beginning by your parents.
There is actually less evidence of such thoughts and even if you would resolve to remember something, let say in 2 days or 10 yeas, its not sure that you would. There is no nicca in sanna-kandha.

Comment: Such references are fairly frequent in the Pali Canon. Again, I will post a reference in the next few days. I do hope you realize just how onerous it is to have to document every allusion with specific textual references in a chat forum. Nevertheless I am glad to do it if it furthers dharma knowledge. The Pali Canon is a long and tedious work which it is understandably more difficult to study than sectarian secondary sources. Nonetheless it is the most important resource for Buddhism.

Comment: The answer argument sound very clear and if there is a fairly frequent its will be much relaxing after being really sure about it. Mudita, Mr Duncan.

Comment: In "How to Be United in Future Lives," in Bhikku Bodhi's In the Buddha's Words, pp. 121f., Bodhi quotes A 4:55;II 61-62, the story of Nakulapita and Nakulamata, a husband and wife who perform an Act of Truth in order to be reborn together. There are other references too in the Pali Canon to intentional rebirth, esp deva rebirth. In addition, according to the Mahavamsa, a non-canonical work on the history of Sri Lanka, Moggaliputta-Tissa intentionally reincarnates in order to preside over the Third Buddhist Council, showing that the concept of intentional rebirth is not exclusively Tibetan.

Comment: [This story](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.055.than_en.html) is usually interpreted as "if people wish to meet each other again, they need to have the same tendency", such is no evidence for a specific birth at all and the interpretation is an interpretation. Atma has no doubt that there as certain ideas like in certain later mahayana ideas in certain commentaries. But actually no, so far, in the Buddhas teachings. Sadhu for your effort and still looking forward to see that Atma was wrong.

Comment: The story clearly is that the husband and wife wish to be reborn together in their next rebirth and that the Buddha says that this can be done consciously and with intention on their part, by deliberately cultivating the "same tendencies" to which you refer. Being reborn together in the future is a specific rebirth.  I have answered this question now and see no point in pursuing it further.

Comment: if they like to "...see one another not only in the present life but also in the life to come, they should..." might give such an idea if searched after it, but it does not say when, how, where... they would see themselves again, if "both!" do this and that... If Mr. Alexander puts under "intentionally influence" being born in heaven, that: yes. Good deeds lead to such. But Atma guesses it was more thought in ways of "i like to be born as such and such, there and there, meeting this and that, after death" and then even kill one self to be the baby of the new king. No, Mr. Alexander Duncan.

Answer (score 0):

One perspective not mentioned in other answers is that going through the bardo is a traumatic experience. This is the primary reason for not maintaining memory between rebirths. The other primary reason being that memories are a physical aspect of the brain.

That being said, karmic seeds are said to grow,  not just naturally, but also because of psychological propensity to repeat the same actions.

I am not sure if it is said that these propensities carry from life to life, or just the karma from them. It seems that it in some way must. Not identity though...  but a type of personna or personality.  However now I get off topic, so I will cease my ramblings.

Comment: What should Bardo be? A distance between two railway stations, Mr/Mrs Hellyale? Such ideas are unknown in Buddhas teachings and merely an adoption of native religion found in every culture, even in Theravada folk Buddhism.

Comment: The bardo translates as the in-between

Comment: The Tibetans tradition includes the bardo as does Mahayana and Vajrayana.

Comment: In between what and who? And even if those and them would include such, how does such fit to the Buddhas teachings? Mr/Mrs Hellyale.

Comment: @samana johann rebirth and karma kind of fall apart without it.  At least as a coherent logical system... Between death and rebirth is where the bardo is...  Some sects of Buddhism reject it and propose instantaneous rebirth as an alternative

Comment: Atma asks again: what would it be called if a bardo (what ever that should be) comes into being? What would it be called if a bardo ceases? Simply birth, simply death. So after birth there follows death, and after death, there follows birth. There is such as a in between in samsara, Mr/Mrs Hellyale.

Comment: There is a period of experience between the two states.  Yes things are impermanent,  the state of experience between death and rebirth is called bardo.

Comment: Also,  I ate breakfast today,  the breakfast no longer exists.  Do I say my day is only waking?  Only driving to work?  Of course not... We should probably take this into chat if you want to discuss further

Comment: Did you had, did your mind had only a millisecond break today? Watch it. There is not a single time that mind does not arise and passes, arises after having passed. Or you take the breath, that is not so fast, to begin with, Mr/Mrs Hellyale

Comment: This is true,  but does not change our previous discussion,  the discussion still occured.  There seems to be a disconnect between us.

Comment: There is no such as a disconnection in ones stream in samsara, and thats the point, so such ideas of bardo and what ever, is simply distraction and useless. Try to find the bardo stage of a breath and then investigate of what it actually is. Investigate the time between the breath out and the breath in and what mind is making.

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you over the ontology of the bardo.  You can't experience the bardo by doing breathing meditation.  It occurs when your body dies (if it occurs) and yes,  your body will die.

Comment: So its something out of samsara? And where does your knowledge come from? Life is not bound to body, there are existences which have fine or no bodies, still it is birth after death. 1, 4, or 5 blatant aggregates coming into being and decay. Your notion is important to the OP question, since it assumes something lasting which should carry such as remembrance.

Comment: Your argumentation style is sloppy,  I wish you would stick to one point at a time,  instead of hopping around.  It is not something out of samsara.  In source of information is the Tibetan book of the Dead and lectures and talks about it.  From Tibetan Rinpoche s

Comment: I was referring to you specifically,  you have a body , no?  I have never assumed anything lasting.

Comment: So what should then in between death and birth and what should transport ordinary remembrance? Atma never sad that such things are not talked in certain books and tradition, but asked how such should find hold in the teachings of the Buddha. The tibetan book of death is not that old.

Comment: Sounds like a good question to ask the stack.  Some of my previous questions deal with the subject as well.  You could also research it yourself.

Comment: So that means your answer does not have any hold? Or if we find a way to go over the state of bardo, everything will be take with one into next live.

Comment: No, It means I am done going back and forth with you. Perhaps see this question : http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/10419/at-what-point-in-the-path-is-one-able-to-recall-their-past-lives if you are truly curious.

Comment: Yes, back and forth means birth and death with no exit because not remembering the whole loop. To know that and the exist is lasting finally knowledge. So there is a bardo in between that loop? (no worry you do nothing with my person)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33636/discussion-between-hellyale-and-samana-johann).

Comment: Is that a public place? How would Atma be able to access if such is an invitation?

Comment: @Bhante. It would be good if words such as these *"...so such ideas of bardo and what ever, is simply distraction and useless..."* is being carefully used when relating to a tradition or lineage. We have a [*"Be-nice-policy"*](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) on Buddhism SE that all users should follow. We have many different traditions in here and all traditions are welcome and should be respected. Hope you will enjoy your time here.

Comment: @Lanka who is Bhante? Did I miss something?

Comment: @SamanaJohann the chat is public, anyone who enters the room can view it.

Comment: @SamanaJohann simply click the link to enter the room.

Comment: @Hellyale. Samana Johann is Bhante.

Comment: @Lanka oh I see

Comment: Mr/Mrs @Lanka, that was a question. But sadhu for taking are!

Comment: Sorry the maybe foolish question: Which link?

Comment: @Bhante. There is a link to the chat room with Hellyale. The text is in blue. Try to press the link and you will be taken to the chat.

Comment: @SamanaJohann "continue this discussion in chat." are the words to click. up above ^^^ No need to apologize

Comment: You have a hard with Atma in this case :-) Sometimes we are pointed on something and have no way to see it. Ohh... The browser "find" function helped Atma out.